# No se muestra el dato en la variable

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

estoy haciendo un procedimiento almacenado el cual según el año si es 2023 te aumenta un 10% y si es 2024 un 5%, esta condición la tengo en una función que solamente en la consulta la llamo pasándole los datos por parámetros, entonces a la hora de mostrar el resultado en la variable no se me imprime, las otras tres si dni, nombre y sueldo, pero sueldoAumentado no me aparece, y no entiendo el porque, les dejo con la función.

Esta es la función

```
CREATE FUNCTION ACTUALIZAR_SUELDO_JJ
       (p_sueldo NUMBER,pAnio NUMBER) 
      RETURN NUMBER
      IS
          v_SUELDO_AUMENTADO NUMBER;
      BEGIN
          V_SUELDO_AUMENTADO:=0;
          IF pAnio>2023 then 
          v_SUELDO_AUMENTADO:=p_sueldo*1.10;
          ELSE 
          v_SUELDO_AUMENTADO:=p_sueldo*1.05;
          RETURN v_SUELDO_AUMENTADO;
END;
```

este es el procedimiento almacenado:

```
PROCEDURE SP_AUMENTO_SUELDO_ANIO(p_anio NUMBER)
is
v_dni VARCHAR2(40);
v_nombre VARCHAR2(40);
v_sueldo NUMBER;
v_sueldoAumentado NUMBER;
begin
for datos in(
SELECT empleados.documento, empleados.nombre, empleados.sueldo,
    ACTUALIZAR_SUELDO_JJ(empleados.sueldo,p_anio)
    into v_dni, v_nombre, v_sueldo, v_sueldoAumentado
    FROM empleados_pruebas_JJ empleados 
)
LOOP
    v_dni:=datos.documento;
    v_nombre:=datos.nombre;
    v_sueldo:=datos.sueldo;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DNI: '||v_dni || ',  Nombre: ' || v_nombre || ', Sueldo: ' || v_sueldo || ', Sueldo Aumentado ' || v_sueldoaumentado  );

end loop;
end;
END PCK_PRUEBAS_JJ;
```

El resultado me muestra los datos de los 3 parametros principales, pero el de la variable v_sueldoAumentado no me lo muestra, agradecería vuestra ayuda, gracias de antemano

Comment: porque no se como es con el cursor, tengo el procedimiento dentro de un paquete hago click derecho sobre el nombre del procedimiento, escribo el dato en el valor que me pide, y ejecuto la consulta

Comment: ¿Te fijaste que estás asignando _v_sueldoAumentado_ a sí mismo? :)

Comment: Si de hecho, quite esa linea, y probé solo a llamarlo en el output, pero nada

Comment: Copie la función antigua, ya lo corregi

Comment: Si quitaste esa línea de la asignación a sí mismo, seguís sin asignar _v_sueldoAumentado_ a lo que estás obteniendo del `SELECT`. Insisto en que busques cómo funciona la sintaxis del cursor, porque realmente esas asignaciones extra de _v_dni_, _v_nombre_ y _v_sueldo_ (en el `INTO`) no deberían existir, ya que luego de nuevo estás asignando esos valores en el `LOOP`.

Comment: Estoy con la misma duda que cuando pregunte xD

Comment: De nuevo: ¿te fijaste que estás asignando _v_sueldoAumentado_ a sí mismo en el procedimiento? Compará qué de diferente tiene con las asignaciones de _v_dni_, _v_nombre_ y _v_sueldo_.

Comment: COMO YA TE DIJE ANTES HABIA QUITADO LA LINEA, PERO VOY A QUITARLA DE AQUÍ MEJOR, PARA QUE QUEDE CLARO

Comment: El punto es que no hay que quitar la línea... Le falta anteponer algo al valor que asignás a _v_sueldoAumentado_...

Comment: Pues si lo sabes, te agradecerías que me lo dijeras

Comment: ESTA PREGUNTA ESTA SOLUCIONADA

Comment: Si ya tienes respuesta a tu pregunta, ¡no olvides responderla y aceptar la respuesta!

Comment: Mediante un cursor, en el bucle le paso la función que actualiza el salario, ese es el resumen rápido de la respuesta que encontré y me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Te comento cómo creo que deberías hacerlo y por qué:

En primer lugar la primera función no requiere ningún dato. De la forma que la utilizas estás obligando al motor de base de datos a ejecutarla una vez por cada línea que utilizas. Yo la quitaría del cursor. No hace más que ralentizarlo.

En segundo lugar, lo que te dice el compañero. Así no se usan los cursores. tienes que quitar los into de la definición del cursor.

De este modo te quedaría así el procedimiento:

```sql
PROCEDURE SP_AUMENTO_SUELDO_ANIO(p_anio NUMBER)
is
v_dni VARCHAR2(40);
v_nombre VARCHAR2(40);
v_sueldo NUMBER;
v_sueldoAumentado NUMBER;
v_aumentoSueldo NUMBER;
begin
v_aumentoSueldo := ACTUALIZAR_SUELDO_JJ(p_anio);
for datos in(
SELECT empleados.documento, empleados.nombre, empleados.sueldo,
    FROM empleados_pruebas_JJ empleados 
)
LOOP
    v_dni:=datos.documento;
    v_nombre:=datos.nombre;
    v_sueldo:=datos.sueldo* v_aumentoSueldo ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DNI: '||v_dni || ',  Nombre: ' || v_nombre || ', Sueldo: ' || v_sueldo || ', Sueldo Aumentado ' || v_sueldoaumentado  );

end loop;
end;
END PCK_PRUEBAS_JJ;
```

No lo he compilado, puede que haya algún error pero básicamente sería así.